# Why has installing Heroku Toolbelt killed my Rails development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently migrated to a new Mac. I had a few problems with PostgreSQL but otherwise I think it went smoothly and I was able to use my Rails app's local development environment.

Then I installed Heroku Toolbelt on the new Mac. Now I get the following errors...

```
$ rspec
/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/better_errors-0.3.2/lib/better_errors/core_ext/exception.rb:9: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
```

[See more in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4499700)...]

Why? What does it mean? And how can I fix it?

Thanks! (Heroku Toolbelt worked fine with this app on my old Mac.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know the cause, but the solution was:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/heroku 
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/heroku
gem uninstall heroku
gem install heroku
```

Then reinstall [Heroku Toolbelt](http://toolbelt.heroku.com)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure better_errors and binding_of_caller gems are in development group (not test) in your Gemfile.

Comment: ...and make sure it's the `:development` group only, and not `group :development, :test`